# -[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance Error in Objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, json, sqlite

I try to insert Json Datas to sqlite database. I got data from another class and they are in a dictionary (responce.item) but I can't insert to database. I got an error like this: unrecognized selector sent to instance. How can I solve this problem? My method is below. Thanks for your reply.

**edited code:**

```
-(void)processDoneWithRequestName:(NSString*)tagName{

sqlite3_stmt *stmt=nil;
sqlite3 *cruddb;

const char *sql = "INSERT INTO LabUpdate (IsSuccess, ProducerId, Latitude, Longitude, Altitude, Slope, SampleDate, PackageNo, Status, Description) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";            

//NSArray *pathsArray=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
NSString *doumentDirectoryPath=@"/Users/ds/Desktop/SqliteTest/SqliteTest";
NSString *cruddatabase=[doumentDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SqliteTestDb.sqlite"];

if ([tagName isEqualToString:Logins]) {

    int keys = [[response.item objectForKey:@"Lipton"] count];
    NSLog(@"count %i",keys);
    for (int i=0; i<keys; i++)
    {

        NSString *str1 =[[[response.item objectForKey:@"Lipton"] objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"IsSuccess"];
        NSString *str2 =[[[response.item objectForKey:@"Lipton"] objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"ProducerId"];
        NSString *str3 =[[[response.item objectForKey:@"Lipton"] objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"Latitude"];
        NSString *str4 =[[[response.item objectForKey:@"Lipton"] objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"Longitude"];
        NSString *str5 =[[[response.item objectForKey:@"Lipton"] objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"Altitude"];
        NSString *str6 =[[[response.item objectForKey:@"Lipton"] objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"Slope"];
        NSString *str7 =[[[response.item objectForKey:@"Lipton"] objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"SampleDate"];
        NSString *str8 =[[[response.item objectForKey:@"Lipton"] objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"PackageNo"];
        NSString *str9 =[[[response.item objectForKey:@"Lipton"] objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"Status"];
        NSString *str10 =[[[response.item objectForKey:@"Lipton"] objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"Description"];
        NSLog(@"str1 %@",str1);
        NSLog(@"str2 %@",str2);
        NSLog(@"str3 %@",str3);
        NSLog(@"str4 %@",str4);
        NSLog(@"str5 %@",str5);
        NSLog(@"str6 %@",str6);
        NSLog(@"str7 %@",str7);
        NSLog(@"str8 %@",str8);
        NSLog(@"str9 %@",str9);
        NSLog(@"str10 %@",str10);




        sqlite3_open([cruddatabase UTF8String], &cruddb);
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(cruddb, sql, 1, &stmt, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 1, [str1 integerValue]);
        sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 2, [str2 integerValue]);
        sqlite3_bind_double(stmt, 3, [str3 floatValue]);
        sqlite3_bind_double(stmt, 4, [str4 floatValue]);
        sqlite3_bind_double(stmt, 5, [str5 floatValue]);
        sqlite3_bind_double(stmt, 6, [str6 floatValue]);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 7, [str7 UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 8, [str8 integerValue]);
        sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 9, [str9 integerValue]);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 10, [str10 UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);


        sqlite3_step(stmt);
        sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
        sqlite3_close(cruddb); 



    }



}
```

}

Comment: Which error exactly u r getting. Post the whole error.

Comment: Can you post an example of your JSON payload?

Comment: ok, I solve problem with using -objectAtIndex: but it enter to for loop one time. and there is no record in database file. :S How can I do?

Comment: I edited my code now I can access all value in dictionary but I can not see in database table. How can I solve?

Answer (score 4):

That error means that the object is an `NSArray` not an `NSDictionary`. You can access the dictionary objects using `-objectAtIndex:`.

EDIT: It's hard to tell from the information you've provided, but try changing this line:

```
int keys = [[response.item objectForKey:@"Lipton"] count];
```

to this:

```
int keys = [[[response.item objectForKey:@"Lipton"] objectAtIndex:0] count];
```

or:

```
int keys = [[[response.item objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Lipton"] count];
```

Like I said, I can't give a decisive answer without more information.

Comment: ok I use objectAtIndex but the keys's count 1 so I can only enter 1 time. what can I do now?

Comment: Ok I already solve this problem thanks for your reply but now it crash in my RequestResponce Class where I call the above code [delegate processDoneWithRequestName:headerTag]; How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does your delegate implement that method?

Comment: What class is that method in, and what class is `delegate`?

Comment: error: Assertion failure in -[ViewController processDoneWithRequestName:], /Users/ds/Desktop/SqliteTest/SqliteTest/ViewController.m:186